# Alternative phrase for "fire sales"

Tags: united-states, stocks, terminology

According to investopedia:

> A fire sale consists of selling goods or assets at heavily discounted
>   prices. Fire sale originally referred to the discount sale of goods
>   that were damaged by fire. Now it more commonly refers to any sale
>   where the seller is in financial distress. In the context of the
>   financial markets, a fire sale refers to a situation where securities
>   that are trading well below their intrinsic value, such as during
>   prolonged bear markets.

### Qustion

If I wanted to convey this kind of meaning without the undue 'jargony' connotation that "fire sale" has, what are my options? I had a few ideas, but either they don't exactly roll off the tongue or they seemed to lose part of the feeling, and I wondered if there was anything more conventional.

I want something that sounds slightly more formal; can be multiple words.

My ideas:

- heavily discounted (lacks fear/awe component)
- distressed stocks (vague?)

Comment: By intrinsic value do you mean "book value"?

Comment: Just don't use "pennies on the dollar," the connotation to that one is that the author doesn't have a clue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about English language usage belong on English.SE, not money.SE.

Comment: "Red tag sale" springs to mind.  Deep discounts without the implied desperation.  At least it's fairly common around here (Canada.)

Comment: @RonJohn Then why does the [tag:terminology] have this in its description: "alternative names for concepts, ect" I think my question falls well within that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few off the top of my head:

- Clearance sale (old models, excess stock etc.)
- Salvage sale (for damaged, excess or used goods)
- Stocktake sale (typically done shortly  before the end of a fiscal year, to simplify the stocktake)
- Runout sale (typical for cars, with updated models/manufacturing year arriving)
- Liquidation sale (company is short of cash or  bankrupt, needs to convert assets to cash quickly)
- Forced sale (sale forced by finance institution)
- Reposession/Foreclosure (typically used for vehicles or real estate where debt finance/mortgage  obligations have not been met)
- Closing down sale (used by every rug shop on the planet)